# Form Not Submitting DateTimePicker Field

Tags: html, forms

In the HTML code below I have a form that has a datetimepicker and a number of
dynamically generated checkboxes. If the form is submitted via the submit button, all the checkbox data is passed to the back-end as expected, but the datetimepicker entry is not. Sorry if this is newbish question but I'm new to front-end work. Thanks!

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h4>Allergic Reaction History</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h4>Report An Allergic Reaction</h4>
            <form action="{{ url_for('reactions') }}" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10" id="dtpicker">
                        <label class="control-label requiredField" for="datetimepicker1">
                            Reaction date & time:
                            <span class="asteriskField">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class='input-group date form-group' id='datetimepicker1'>
                            <input type='text' class="form-control"/>
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                        </span>
                        </div>
                        <span class="help-block" id="hint_name">
                                        Click the calendar icon to enter date then click the clock icon to enter time.
                                        Approximations are okay.
                                    </span>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(function () {
                                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
                            });
                        </script>
                            <label class="control-label requiredField" for="checkbox">
                                Check all symptoms experienced:
                                <span class="asteriskField">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="checkboxes" id="checkbox-div">
                                {% for s in symptoms %}
                                    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
                                        <input title="{{ s.desc }}" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="{{ s._id }}"/>
                                        {{ s._id }}
                                    </label>
                                {% endfor %}
                                <span class="help-block" id="hint_name">
                                        Hover over the checkbox for a symptom to get more details about it.
                                        </span>
                            </div>
                                <div>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary " name="submit" type="submit">
                                        Submit
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to give your `<input>` a `name` attribute as only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form. See also https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#successful-controls

(Notice that you can access your checkbox value server-side, *but* your checkbox *does* have a `name` attribute.)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!